# assign a value from a java variable to a jsp variable with getProperty

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, variable-assignment, getproperty

So for my project, I need to use JSP to make a test. So I am doing all the calculations for the creations of the problems in a separate java file. Then I assign those to a 2d string array in the java file. So I use

```
<jsp:useBean id = "questionSet" scope = "session" class="Questions.QuestionMaker"/>
```

to run the constructor. Now my problem is using the getProperty action to assign the 2d string array to an existing 2d array in the jsp. I honestly have no idea of how to do this. I tried something like

```
<%String[][] currenQuestions = (jsp:getProperty name = "user" property = "firstName"/)>
```

but needless to say that didn't work.
My teacher is insisting that we have to use getProperty to set the value and we can't do other things. If anyone can help me out please let me know.

Thanks in advance